# Change text on changing image

Tags: android, text, android-view

I have a horizontal scroll view with array list of images and the text field below the scroll view,how could i change the text on changing image in horizontal scrollview.

```
For Example: If the image will show image2 the text will also texted with text2 next when i will scroll the image2 to image3 the text will also move from text2 to text3
```

**Here The image will only scroll, the text view will remain fix, it will change the name with images only**

i have tried every possibilities but i did not get:

here i have used the adapter class in view items i placed the image:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            vi=convertView;


            if(convertView==null){
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.screen, null);

               position_pin = position;

              Holder.images=(ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
              Holder.textview=(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);



             Holder.images.setImageResource(imageIds[position]);
           Holder.text.setText(name);//here name is String 

             vi.setTag(Holder);   

            }

                        return vi;
            }
```

Comment: hi you can use title pager indicator.

Comment: @Priya thanks how to use title pager indicator?

Answer (score 0):

implement the scroll view listener and get the position based on the position we can display the text..

ExampleScrollView exampleScrollView = (ExampleScrollView) findViewById(R.id.example_scroll_view);

exampleScrollView.setOnScrollViewListener( new OnScrollViewListener() {

```
public void onScrollChanged( ExampleScrollView v, int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt ) { 
    Log.d( "Scroller", "I changed!" ); 
}
```

} );

Answer (score 0):

just integrate title pager indicator with view pager.

```
  ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
titleIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

you can find the library project for title pager indicator at
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: using this the image will change on scrolling horizontally

Comment: i want to scroll the images only the text field should remain fixed, it will change the text on getting images

Comment: it will automatically scroll the text when you scrolling the image

Comment: i need that the text should not scroll ,it will change the text with respect to image